# Are Graph Neural Networks algorithm supported in Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb, graph-neural-network

On [the documentation page](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms/machine-learning-graph-analytics/gnn-algorithm) for Graph Neural Networks (GNN) it says that it is not implemented in Memgraph. Is there some workaround for it so that I can use it?

EDIT: it seems that GNN was addeded in the meantime since I've asked the question. I've proposed to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked on the link you provided and it says GNNs have been implemented!
So I guess no workarounds necessary! :)